# How does Cypress.io read the Windows environment variables?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have set my environment variables in 'Cypress.env.json' file, while running the cypress test, it read the Cypress.env variables successfully. But to be more on the security aspect, rather than 'hard-cording' the values, my team asked me to keep this variable as separate 'parameters' which read from Windows 10 Environment variables. How do I achieve this ? It would be really helpful if someone could advise on this.

```
{
"QA_Server": "https://sometestingsite.com",
"username": "testQA",
"password": "Password1234!"
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**From cypress documentation [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables.html#Option-3-CYPRESS):**

Any environment variable on your machine that starts with either `CYPRESS_` or `cypress_` will automatically be added and made available to you.

Conflicting values will override values from `cypress.json` and `cypress.env.json` files.

Cypress will strip off the `CYPRESS_` when adding your environment variables.

**Exporting cypress env variables from the command line:**

```
export CYPRESS_HOST=laura.dev.local

export cypress_api_server=http://localhost:8888/api/v1/
```

If you're using Windows you can set env variables using `set` or `setx` commands.

And in your test files you can call this:

```
Cypress.env()             // {HOST: "laura.dev.local", api_server: "http://localhost:8888/api/v1"}
Cypress.env("HOST")       // "laura.dev.local"
Cypress.env("api_server") // "http://localhost:8888/api/v1/"
```

Comment: Why do we need to export cypress env values from command line ? Sorry I didn’t get that !

Comment: @soccerway you don't need, I just added that as an example.

Comment: This export example is given in the docs, but can you please explain how **export** works with the **command line**? On Windows it is an unknown command.

Comment: Yes, I read those and was about to ask, would like to know how to set the environment variables from Windows command line, so that we can use in Cypress

Comment: @DiogoRocha: I have set the environment variable in windows ...`set CYPRESS_username=cypress` and `set CYPRESS_password=somepassword`..Then in my cypress test i have created two const like this  `const user = Cypress.env('CYPRESS_username');`
   `const psw = Cypress.env('CYPRESS_password')` ....but system throws undefined ...I have tried this way too ..const user = Cypress.env('username')..in both cases it throws undefined error

Comment: Use `setx` command instead `set`. You can find the diference here: https://superuser.com/a/916652

Answer (score 2):

you can read it from windows env variables directly.
to do so use cy.exec with echo. if you run in CMD 'echo %appdata%' it will print the path. i put wrapper around cy.exec as

```
cy.runExec = (js) => {
  cy.log(`--- runnnig node ${js}`);
  cy.exec(js, { failOnNonZeroExit: false }).then((z) => {
    if (z.stderr != undefined) {
      cy.log(`--- stderr`);
      let lines = z.stderr.split("\n");
      for (let n in lines) cy.log(`--- ${n}: ${lines[n]}`);
    }
    if (z.stdout != undefined) {
      cy.log(`--- stdout`);
      let lines = z.stdout.split("\n");
      for (let n in lines) cy.log(`--- ${n}: ${lines[n]}`);
    }      
  });
};
```

and if you call it as `cy.runExec('echo %appdata%')`, it will print same path in cypress output, you can modify this method to get only stdout. you can also save that value using cy.wrap(...).as(...) and get it later.

here is the direct call:

```
cy.getWinEnv = (s) => {
  cy.exec(`echo %${s}%`, { failOnNonZeroExit: false }).then((z) => {
    let out = z.stdout != undefined ? z.stdout : "undefined";
    cy.wrap(out).as(s);
    //do not: return out;
  });
};
```

usage:

```
//read %appdata%
cy.getWinEnv("appdata");

//log %appdata% in cypress
cy.get("@appdata").then((x) => cy.log(`--- ${x}`));
```

yet another update - if you add 'cypress-promise' package, then it is possible to call directly with async/await...

```
cy.getWinEnvEx = async (s) => {
  var out = "undefined yet";
  await cy.exec(`echo %${s}%`, { failOnNonZeroExit: false }).then((z) => {
    if (z == null) {
      cy.log("--- output is null");
    } else {      
      out = z.stdout != undefined ? z.stdout : "undefined";
      //cy.log(`--- z.stdout ${out}`);
    }
  });
  return out;
};

...

it("list windows variables", async () => {
  let z = await cy.getWinEnvEx("USERPROFILE");
  cy.log(`--- USERPROFILE ${z}`);
});
```