# How to refer to an environment variable in json file

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a File Creator task in my release pipeline that creates a `cypress.json` file:

```
{
  "integrationFolder": "D:/a/r1/a/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/tests/integration/",
  "baseUrl": $env:featureReleaseUrl
}
```

As you can see I'm referencing a environmental variable `featureReleaseUrl`.

In a `Azure Powershell` task **before** creating the `cypress.json` file I output the `$env:featureReleaseUrl` variable:

```
write-host $env:featureReleaseUrl
```

Which outputs:

> http://exampleofaurl.azurewebsites.net

So the variable gets set correctly.

When I read the contents of my created `cypress.json` file I see:

```
{
  "integrationFolder": "D:/a/r1/a/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/tests/integration/",
  "baseUrl": $env:featureReleaseUrl
}
```

And when I run Cypress I get:

> `SyntaxError: D:\a\r1\a\_ClientWeb-Build-CI\ShellArtifact\tests\integration\cypress.json: Unexpected token $ in JSON at position 104`

So it looks like when I create the `cypress.json` file it takes the `$env:featureReleaseUrl` as a literal string and not the actual value of the variable.

Any suggestions how I can reference a variable in the creation of a file in Azure dev-ops?

Comment: You'd most likely need a [file transform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/transforms-variable-substitution?view=azure-devops#jsonvarsubs)

Comment: maybe this article can be of use.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52421031/4846648

Comment: Actually changing the `$env:featureReleaseUrl` value to `(featureReleaseUrl)` works! I've created a variable `featureReleaseUrl` to refers to `$(env:featureReleaseUrl)` in the variable section of the pipeline. It looks like it's working. If it does I'll create a answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the harder things when using Azure is when to use what kind of variable.

What I did to fix my problem was not directly reference `$env:featureReleaseUrl` in the creation of the json file:

```
{
  "integrationFolder": "D:/a/r1/a/_ClientWeb-Build-CI/ShellArtifact/tests/integration/",
  "baseUrl": "$(featureReleaseUrl)"
}
```

This variable `$(featureReleaseUrl)` refers to:

[image]

This might not be the fastest solution, but it works.